# PhpUnitTests Doctrine Entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

I want to test my application. For know i have a simple controller/action where i print two values from two different doctrine entities (A and B). If i had only one value from one entity my test works fine but for my current situation it will not work.

```
public function testIndexActionCanBeAccessed()
{
    $a = $this->getMock('\Application\Entity\A');
    $a->expects($this->once())->method('getName')->will($this->returnValue('A'));
    $b= $this->getMock('\Application\Entity\B');
    $b->expects($this->once())->method('get')->will($this->returnValue('B'));

    $aRepository = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $aRepository->expects($this->once())->method('find')->will($this->returnValue($a));
    $bRepository = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $bRepository->expects($this->once())->method('find')->will($this->returnValue($b));

    $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $entityManager->expects($this->once())->method('getRepository')->will($this->returnValue($aRepository));
    $entityManager->expects($this->any())->method('getRepository')->will($this->returnValue($bRepository));

    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(true);
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setService('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager', $entityManager);

    $this->dispatch('/myroute/');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
}
```

How can i tell the entitymanager that there could be more than one getRepository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `with()` method to define for which specific method arguments you want to setup your mock. ie:

```
$entityManager
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getRepository')
    ->with($this->equalTo('MyNamespace\Repository\RepositoryA'))
    ->will($this->returnValue($aRepository));
```

And similar for repo b

Btw it would be cleaner to inject your entityManager into your controller through a controller factory. Or better yet, inject both the repositories as a dependency. It will make things a lot cleaner and easier to test.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But can you give me an example how it would be better in your opinion? That would be very very nice. Iam completely new to PhpUnitTests.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at this [blogpost](http://www.zfdaily.com/2012/07/getting-dependencies-into-zf2-controllers/) for more information about getting dependencies in your controller by the use of service factories. Injecting the repositories instead of the entitymanager will make it very clear which repositories your controller uses and you'll not break the [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it solves your initial question?